# numpy equivalent command for Matlab 2D indexing A([],[])

Tags: numpy, indexing, numpy-slicing

I am looking for exact command in Numpy for following Matlab indexing.

Uploaded as picture:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2DJ0.png

I have tried to do similar thing in Numpy:

```py
kk = np.zeros((100,100))
k= np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],
              [ 3,  4,  5],
              [ 6,  7,  8]])
kk[[9,2,7],[9,2,7]] = k
```

But this will throw you error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,3) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (3,)
```

i edit this question, in my case, each indexing is not contiguous, but they are the same for example: kk[[9,2,7],[9,2,7]].

Comment: Can you please clarify what is MATLAB behavior or what would you expect your Python / NumPy code to do?

Comment: Sooner of later you'll need to read about `numpy` advanced-indexing (and `broadcasting`).  MATLAB uses this notation to index blocks.  In `numpy` this indexes a "diagonal".  To get the block the row index needs to be a column vector, Getting the 'diagonal' in MATLAB requires the use of `sub2ind`.

Comment: @norok2, check the picture i attached.

Comment: I saw the pic and I know the MATLAB / Python behavior. What I am trying to say is that adding some text instead of a picture makes the question much easier on whoever might answer or may look at it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If the indexing is contiguous you should use `slice()`s:

```py
import numpy as np


kk = np.zeros((6, 7), dtype=int)
k = np.arange(2 * 3).reshape((2, 3)) + 1
kk[1:3, 1:4] = k
   
print(kk)
# [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 2 3 0 0 0]
#  [0 4 5 6 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Note that `a:b:c` inside `[]` is sugar syntax for `slice(a, b, c)`, with `:c`/`, c` optional and if `a`/`b` should be `None` this can be left out in the shortcut (but not in the functional version) and if only one parameter is set to `slice()`, this is assigned to `b`.

Otherwise, you could use [`numpy.ix_()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```py
import numpy as np


kk = np.zeros((6, 7), dtype=int)
k = np.arange(2 * 3).reshape((2, 3)) + 1
kk[np.ix_((1, 3), (1, 2, 4))] = k
   
print(kk)
# [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 2 0 3 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 4 5 0 6 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Slices are typically way faster and more memory efficient than advanced indexing, and you should prefer them when possible.

Note that `np.ix_()` is just producing index arrays with the correct shapes to trigger the desired indexing:

```py
np.ix_((1, 3), (1, 2, 4))
# (array([[1],
#         [3]]), array([[1, 2, 4]]))
```

Hence, the following would work:

```py
import numpy as np


kk = np.zeros((6, 7), dtype=int)
k = np.arange(2 * 3).reshape((2, 3)) + 1
kk[np.array([1, 3])[:, None], np.array([1, 2, 4])[None, :]] = k
   
print(kk)
# [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 2 0 3 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 4 5 0 6 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Also, `slice`s and `np.ndarray(dtype=int)` can be combined together:

```py
import numpy as np


kk = np.zeros((6, 7), dtype=int)
k = np.arange(2 * 3).reshape((2, 3)) + 1
kk[1:4:2, np.array([1, 2, 4])] = k
   
print(kk)
# [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 2 0 3 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 4 5 0 6 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: I like to contrast the use of `np.ix_` to get the `numpy` block, and `sub2ind` to get the MATLAB 'diagonal'.  What's easiest in one is bit more complicated in the other, and v.v..

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, in my case, the indexing is not continuing.